# Comparing function of binary_search

Tags: c++, c++11, overloading, binary-search

I am trying to run binary_search on vector of custom objects.

```
struct T{
    string name;
    T(string n):name(n){};
    bool operator < (   T * n  ) const {
        return name < n ->  name;
    }
    bool operator == ( T * n ) const {
      return name == n -> name;
    }
};

    vector<T *> t;
    t.push_back(new T("one"));
    t.push_back(new T("two"));
    t.push_back(new T("three"));

bool has_3 = binary_search( t.begin(), t.end(), new T("two") ) ;
    if( has_3 ){
        cout <<"Its there" << endl;
    }
```

The comparation function should be just fine yet when i run the code has_3 equals to 0 = the element isnt present in vector. Is this problem caused by my overloading of < ? I see no reason why this shouldnt find the value. Considering the order of insertion into vector it should be sorted

Thanks for help.

Comment: you operators should take refrences as parameters. Currently you are comparing objects with pointers to objects, ie one would use them like this `T a; T* b; a == b;`

Comment: @tobi303 I am comparing value of object that pointers points to no? e.g  n < n -> name

Comment: yes but think about how you would call that operators, normally you want to compare objects with objects not pointers with objects

Comment: Well if my understanding is correct binary_search iterates and compares the iterator with third parameter , when interator points to first element in vector it would be something like it < T("two) , thus < operator is invoked and it -> name is compared to T -> name , or am i wrong?

Comment: `binary_search` will dereferene the iterator and compare the object in the container with the object you pass as parameter

Comment: actually I would expect a compiler error from your operators, at least they will not be called when you do `T a,b; a == b;`

Comment: @tobi303 well , it would do something like (*it) < third paramaters which still invoked < operator and should make the job done , or am i wrong?

Comment: ups I am sorry I completely overlooked that you have pointers in the vector. Nevertheless the operators are required to take a reference

Comment: good that someone else payed more attention and wrote a nice answer ;)

Comment: just one last comment... to compare the pointers in the vector you would need a comarator that compares a `T*` with a `T*`, while (as already mentioned) your operators try to compare a `T` with a `T*`

Comment: Yea , i created bool myfunction (T * i,T *j) { return (i -> name < j -> name ); } comp function instead of overloading the opetaor , but why overloading compares T to T* , why does it matter? When it derefference iterator it still invokes its < opetator i dont see reason why it should fail.

Answer (score 2):

There are several reasons why this shouldn't find the value:

- The range must be sorted; your range is out of alphabetical order
- Your comparison functionality is defined between `T` and `T*`, while you search a vector of `T*` for a `T*`.

You can fix the first problem by swapping `"two"` and `"three"`, and the second problem by making a vector of `T`:

```
struct T{
    string name;
    T(string n):name(n){};
    bool operator < (   const T &n  ) const {
        return name < n.name;
    }
    // operator == is not necessary for binary_search
};
int main() {
    vector<T> t;
    t.push_back(T("one"));
    t.push_back(T("three"));
    t.push_back(T("two"));
    bool has_3 = binary_search( t.begin(), t.end(), T("two") ) ;
    if( has_3 ){
        cout <<"Its there" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo 1.](http://ideone.com/fHvYhW)

If you do have no way but to construct a vector of pointers, you have this ugly work-around available (I strongly recommend against it):

```
struct T{
    string name;
    T(string n):name(n){};
};
bool operator < (const T& l, const T *r) {
    return l.name < r->name;
}
bool operator < (const T *l, const T &r) {
    return l->name < r.name;
}
```

Now you can search like this:

```
bool has_3 = binary_search( t.begin(), t.end(), T("two") ) ;
if( has_3 ){
    cout <<"Its there" << endl;
}
```

[Demo 2.](http://ideone.com/2x2ToS)

Comment: The key thing is that i need vector of T*

Comment: @trolkura why do you need that? If you really cannot avoid it then at least you should delete the elements ;)

Comment: I will have to sort the vector by two paramaters , name and id , so one vector will hold sorted pointers by name and one by id , the project isnt real i am just playing around.

Comment: If the project isn't real, why are you insisting you need to work with a vector of pointers?    From a perspective of using it with C++ standard algorithms, it is a dumb requirement.

Comment: @trolkura you can make a vector that contains a `struct Foo {std::string name; int id;}` and use two different comparators to sort it. Dont put pointers in the vector if you dont need to and dont use `new` if you dont need to and never ever use `new` without `delete`

Comment: I just came accross past school assigment, where it required to do it this way. I remember i had trouble with exact same thing as now so i became curious again :_

Answer (score 0):

It's a really dumb requirement to work with a vector of pointers to dynamically allocated objects.  But here is an approach that will work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

struct T
{
    std::string name;
    T(std::string n):name(n){};
};

// this is the comparater needed to work with pointers, but it should
//    NOT be a member of T

bool pointer_comparer(const T *left, const T *right)
{
   // this assumes both left and right point to valid objects

    return left->name < right->name;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<T *> t;
    t.push_back(new T("one"));
    t.push_back(new T("two"));
    t.push_back(new T("three"));

    //   t is unsorted.  We need to sort it since binary_search will
    //      ASSUME it is sorted

    std::sort(t.begin(), t.end(), pointer_comparer);

    T *value_needed = new T("two");    
    bool has_3 = std::binary_search( t.begin(), t.end(), value_needed, pointer_comparer);
    if(has_3)
    {
        std::cout <<"Its there" << std::endl;
    }

    //   since we've been stupidly allocating objects, we need to release them

    delete value_needed;
    for (std::vector<T *>::iterator i = t.begin(), end = t.end();
         i != end;  ++i)
    {
         delete (*i);
    }

    //   and since t now contains a set of dangling pointers, we need to discard them too

    t.resize(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Why do I say the requirement to work with a vector of pointers to dynamically allocated objects.   Compare the above with an approach that works with a `vector<T>` rather than a `vector<T *>`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

struct T
{
    std::string name;
    T(std::string n):name(n){};
    bool operator < (const T &) const
    {
        return name < n.name;
    };
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<T> t;
    t.push_back(T("one"));
    t.push_back(T("two"));
    t.push_back(T("three"));

    //   t is unsorted.  We need to sort it since binary_search will
    //      ASSUME it is sorted

    std::sort(t.begin(), t.end());
    bool has_3 = std::binary_search(t.begin(), t.end(), T("two"));
    if(has_3)
    {
        std::cout <<"Its there" << std::endl;
    }

    //  we need do nothing here.  All objects use above will be properly released

    return 0;
}
```

Note:  I've written the above so it works with ALL C++ standards.  Assuming C++11 and later, simplifications are possible in both cases.